# Symfony2 access control not working

Tags: php, symfony

In my access control I have a bunch of rules but none of them seem to be working. I belong to a group that does not have the role and I am still able to access all the routes. I tried adding dollar signs to the end of the paths but that did not work. I also tried reordering the paths and that failed as well. Any advice will help!

here is my security.yml file

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
         fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/system/staff/add, roles: ROLE_ADD_STAFF }
        - { path: ^/system/staff/edit, roles: ROLE_EDIT_STAFF }
        - { path: ^/system/staff, roles: ROLE_VIEW_STAFF }

        - { path: ^/system/profile/edit, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/system/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

        - { path: ^/system/officer/add, roles: ROLE_ADD_OFFICER }
        - { path: ^/system/officer/edit, roles: ROLE_EDIT_OFFICER }
        - { path: ^/system/officer, roles: ROLE_VIEW_OFFICER }

        - { path: ^/system/job/add, roles: ROLE_ADD_JOBS }
        - { path: ^/system/job/edit, roles: ROLE_EDIT_JOBS }
        - { path: ^/system/job, roles: ROLE_VIEW_JOBS }

        - { path: ^/system/company/add, roles: ROLE_ADD_COMPANIES }
        - { path: ^/system/company/edit, roles: ROLE_EDIT_COMPANIES }
        - { path: ^/system/company, role: ROLE_VIEW_COMPANIES }

        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/system, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

for example my current group does not have the  `ROLE_EDIT_STAFF` role yet I am still able to access the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you make a request symfony will check your access controls to find one that works.

When you request `/system/staff/edit` heres what happens.

For your setup it finds:

```
- { path: ^/system/staff/edit, roles: ROLE_EDIT_STAFF }
```

But since you dont have the role `ROLE_EDIT_STAFF` it moves on.

It now matches:

```
- { path: ^/system/staff, roles: ROLE_VIEW_STAFF }
```

Because your route does start with ^/system/staff. And you have `ROLE_VIEW_STAFF` so you are granted access.

In additon to that one you have:

```
- { path: ^/system, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Which means that anyone who has the `ROLE_USER` can access any route that starts with `/system`.

Whether its `/system/admin/delete-all` for just `/system` It matches them both.

If you want to use strict route controls i would recommend dropping the `^` from the start of the routes unless you really mean to match any routes starting with what follows the `^`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but that did not fix the issue

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. FOSUserBundle handles most everything that is going on lol The roles are created with a command line command and when the user is created the role is chosen at that point. The associations in the database are all correct

Comment: the users are a part of groups that have multiple roles. When I went to check in the database the group that I belong to does not have the `ROLE_EDIT_STAFF` role

Comment: When you load a page using app_dev.php at the bottom of the page their should be a profile. There you can look and see what roles that user is actually getting.

Comment: I figured it out see the new answer

Comment: your right even when I am a part of a group that only have `ROLE_USER` the profile says I have all the roles. I do not know why that is

Comment: I found out that symfony was caching my roles for some reason. If I change my roles and dont log out it keeps my roles. Once I log out and log back in the roles are changed and the access control works